# SQL Server Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to add data into my Table using Visual Studio 2015,but I got this error:

```
An exception of type "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" occurred in System.Data.dll but was not processed in user code
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

And here is my code:

```
    protected void btSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "')",con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgJVC.png)

[this is information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Fgq.png)

Comment: Is your ID auto increment? Or else you will have to specify when you insert.   Concatenating user input directly is not a very good Practise. This makes your code susceptible to SQL injection. For example a user can easily enter 'drop database 'database name';' into your textfields and the database will be gone. Use Stored Procedures instead

Comment: @JIng cheng can you show us your table design?

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
insert into User
     values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "')"
```

When using `insert`, you should always include the column names.  And, when putting values into the query string, you should use parameters.

Once you fix the code, your problem will go away.

Comment: If you are inserting into all the fields of your database which is not auto increment, you do not have to specify the column names.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!